# UPDATING a variable inside a loop (python)

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, while-loop, dice

I am trying to create dice for my board game using loops. However, the variable pos won't update itself so that the next time the for loop is triggered it starts from its previous value and not 0. At the moment each time the for loop is being triggered the pos starts by default from 0 and doesn't get updated after each run. Meaning the player would always go back to
square 0.

this is what i have coded so far:

```
    w = True

    while w == True:
        dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)

        player1_dice = input("\nBULL (P1): Please press 'ENTER' to roll the dice ")
        if player1_dice == "":
            print("BULL (P1) rolled a", dice1)

        elif player1_dice != "":
            print("BULL (P1): Please make sure to press 'ENTER' ")

        dieValue = dice1
        pos = 0

        for pos in range(dieValue) :
            posi = pos + 1
            P1_pos =  player1.goto(p1_list[posi])
            pos = posi
```

Comment: Why did you expect that the line `pos = 0` does not reset the variable to 0?

Comment: You can't have `pos` be both  a retained value and a loop variable.  Move `pos = 0` out of the loop, and change the loop variable to something like `i`.  The loop then becomes `pos += 1` / `P1_pos = platyr1.goto(p1_list[pos])`

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I don't know why I haven't thought of it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`pos` itself does not change when you change it in the loop, because `range(dieValue)` is an iterable that the for loop is looping over. You can thinking of the range precisely as `(0, 1, 2, ..., dieValue - 1)`.

To maintain the position of the player, you have to record the position outside of of the while loop. Furthermore, you should change the for loop to be

```
for _ in range(dieValue):
    pos += 1
    P1_pos = player1.goto(p1_list[pos])
```

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you mean now. I will amend the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, then the position of a player should be passed as a parameter of this function/method. Then you would sum dice1 and this position to get a new position. Or you would access the pos of a player through player1.pos().

Another weird thing is that you initiate `pos` to 0 and then you also use `pos` in the for-loop. In your for-loop `pos` is 0 in the first iteration, 1 in the second, and so on till you get to the value of `pos` == dice1-1 (if there is range(4), values of `pos` would be 0,1,2,3).